# Python 3.7 hangs up getting Outlook Calendar Start or End Properties of an Appointment Item

Tags: python, python-3.x, outlook, calendar

This code worked ok in Python 3.5.2. in the same machine.

In Python 3.7.0 it hangs up when you try to get the Appointment Properties Start or End.
It hangs up just with the first request for Start or End. No error message appears.

Tested under Windows 10, both in Command Console and with Jupyter Notebook.

Any advice or other libraries needed to include?

```
import win32com.client
import datetime

outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
calendar = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(9)
appointments = calendar.Items
appointments.Sort("[Start]")
appointments.IncludeRecurrences = "True"

#This block restrict the time range. Doesn't change the hang up
begin = datetime.date(2018, 9, 1)  #year, month, day
end = datetime.date(2018, 10, 1)
print(f"Activities from: {begin}, to: {end}")
restriction = "[Start] >= '" + begin.strftime("%d/%m/%Y") + "' AND [End] <= '" +end.strftime("%d/%m/%Y") + "'"
print("restriction:", restriction)
restrictedItems = appointments.Restrict(restriction)

# The problem arise accessing as a unique item
appointment = restrictedItems[1]
print(appointment.Subject)
print(appointment.Organizer)
print(appointment.Start)
print(appointment.End)

# Also hangs up inside a loop of appointments
for appointment in restrictedItems:
    print(appointment.Subject)
    print(appointment.Organizer)
    print(appointment.Start)
    print(appointment.End)
```

Comment: Also tested in Windows 7 with similar results

Comment: For Python 3.7.0 you need to use pywin32 224 (or later). Thanks to Mark Hammond who generated this new version of pywin32 that solves the issue.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For Python 3.7.0 you need to use pywin32 224 (today's last version).
Thanks to Mark Hammond who generated this new version of pywin32 that solves the issue.

Comment: Can you please help me out with the code snippet here?